# How to fix invalid scope (400 bad request) with google ml api

Tags: java, scala, google-cloud-platform, gcp-ai-platform-training

I tried to send a predict request with Java google ml api. My content is an array of int (it's from an image), i create a JsonHttpContent, but not sure it's the way to do the predict request. 
i have the credentials json key locally. 
Here the request :

```
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
implicit val formats = DefaultFormats

val credentials = "creds.json"
val httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport
val jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory
val discovery = new Discovery(httpTransport, jsonFactory, null)
val api = discovery.apis.getRest("ml", "v1").execute
val method = api.getResources.get("projects").getMethods.get("predict")
val param = new JsonSchema
val projectId = "ml-training"

val modelId = "my-model"
param.set("name",s"""projects/$projectId/models/$modelId""")
val url = new GenericUrl(UriTemplate.expand(api.getBaseUrl + method.getPath, param, true))
val contentType = "application/json"
val payload  = Map("instances" -> Array(255,255,255))
val content = new JsonHttpContent(jsonFactory,payload)

println(write(content))

val credential = GoogleCredential.fromStream(new FileInputStream(credentials))
val requestFactory = httpTransport.createRequestFactory(credential)
val request = requestFactory.buildRequest(method.getHttpMethod, url, content)
val response = request.execute.parseAsString
println(response)
  }
```

Here is the error :

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException: 400 Bad Request
{
  "error" : "invalid_scope",
  "error_description" : "Bad Request"
}
```

I don't understand the source of my problem. Is it from the content of the request ? 
Thank's in advance

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I found :

```
val credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(new FileInputStream(creds)).createScoped(
  java.util.Arrays.asList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform")
)
credentials.refreshIfExpired()
val accessToken = credentials.getAccessToken
```

And use the accessToken inside a header of and http call